# Artifactory: Table 'artdb.node_props' doesn't exist

Tags: installation, upgrade

Trying to upgrade Artifactory 2.6.7 to 3.0.x and getting these errors/exceptions:

```
2015-08-14 15:37:53,979 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:196) - Failed to run configuration conversion.
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Failed to check for config 'artifactory.config.xml' existence: Table 'artdb.configs' doesn't exist

2015-08-14 16:16:02,808 [art-init] [ERROR] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:85) - Application could not be initialized: Table 'artdb.configs' doesn't exist
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
```

Browsing the database, I can see that a few of the tables are there, but not all. Artifactory's `configure.mysql.sh` script runs without errors.

Note that I may have screwed up the order of the restore and enabling MySQL support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to re-initialize the database. What did work was to delete all of the tables in the `artdb` database (which were all empty anyway), find the correct database schema for the version of Artifactory and apply it (you can use your favorite MySQL client).

You can find the schemas in Artifactory's source control: http://subversion.jfrog.org/artifactory/

For example, here is the MySQL schema for v 3.0.1: http://subversion.jfrog.org/artifactory/public/tags/3.0.1/storage/db/src/main/resources/mysql/mysql.sql